# Canopy is having difficulties updating packages, "AbortedOperationDetected"

Tags: python, package, enthought, package-managers, canopy

I run Canopy version Version: 2.1.3.3542 (64 bit) on Windows 10. 
Canopy cant manage to update any package, all results in the same

log output for a numpy update (for example):

```
Warming up...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action_worker.py", line 54, in run
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action.py", line 196, in execute
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 626, in <lambda>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line 1051, in _install
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py", line 152, in install_packages_prompt
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py", line 137, in _install_packages_prompt
PackagesInstallationError: installation of packages ['numpy 1.11.3-3'] failed. Details below: 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\edm_api.py", line 64, in wrapper
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\edm_api.py", line 384, in install_command
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\edm_api.py", line 414, in _install_packages_command
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\edm\core\packages_manager.py", line 124, in decorator
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\edm\core\packages_manager.py", line 219, in install_command
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\edm\core\packages_manager.py", line 223, in _install_command
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\edm\core\packages_manager.py", line 549, in _compute_fix_aborted_actions
AbortedOperationDetected: Aborted operation detected in environment 'User'
```

There is absolutly 0 results on google for this error code, so stackexchange is my last resort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a previous update was force-aborted, possibly leaving the environment corrupted. Assuming that you are using the standard installer, then it should suffice to

- reboot your computer
- temporarily disable your anti-virus software if possible (or at least disable its more intrusive / slow functionality, such as online checking each of the tens of thousands of package files that Canopy provides),
- from the Canopy Tools menu, select Troubleshoot => Reset Python environment